# How to extract out data from an embedded google maps?

Tags: kml

Is there a way to extract out the data from this embedded google maps?

https://hinkleyconnection.co.uk/map-and-timeline/

Answer (score 1):

For this site the data is loaded by getting the kml to a static address, to ding it you need to examin the documents ent by the sites and find the one with the map data. There are different methods to store them and to extract them and they vary on the implementation and provider.

Concretely the static address that is valid as of posting this is https://www.nationalgrid.com/electricity-transmission/sites/et/files/documents/map-april-21.kmz

This one is easy, something the data is a javascript string in and xml container, you'd need to fiddle it to make the data importable, but thankfully this isn't needed here.